# Cutting cardboard tubing

Tags: cutting

I’m looking for advice on how to cut cardboard tubing into a T. The tubes I have are approximately 11” OD with a 1/4” thickness. I’m able to cut with a jigsaw but having difficulty cutting them with a nice fit. Any ideas?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not seem to relate to home improvement.

Comment: The question could apply to fitting tubular concrete forms.

Comment: Is the question about cutting or layout and design? The answers below diverge greatly on that point.

Comment: This question could equally apply to cutting steel, copper or plastic pipe. It's about making a good joint, regardless of the material in use

Comment: I use hole saws to cut into larger metal pipes and weld them if your side tube matches up with a hole saw it can make a proper circle.

Comment: It is mostly about layout and design, as I find the jigsaw cuts well. I do not have a hole saw large enough for this either

Comment: Please revise to clarify that. Your mention of a jigsaw threw me, and it's not clear where you're running into a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Many moons ago, last century, I used and appreciated a program known as winmiter. It no longer works on today's technological magic, but there's an online free alternative known as [Pipe Joint Template](http://www.harderwoods.com/pipetemplate.php) with an option to purchase and download an offline version with more features.

[image: pipe template softare]

The program allows you to print a paper template to mark the cuts necessary to have a clean fit to the joined tubing. The original winmiter program was quite capable and I suspect that this one is as well.

There are other similar options via CAD programs such as Fusion 360, solvespace and I suspect SolidWorks and others, but this is certainly among the simpler methods to accomplish a good fit.

Comment: If you need to make a _really_ tight joint for holding back moisture (concrete) or because it's going to be visible as a finished item: I'd suggest cutting a bit (~1mm) off your line then sanding the final distance to the line to ensure you have a very tight fit. You can double check as you're getting there and even account for minor inaccuracies in the piece you're joining to by sanding more or less.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "fishmouth joints" which you'll find in bicycle frames, tubular hot rod frames, and light aircraft frames, among others. Websites catering to those pursuits will likely have information and even patterns or better yet pattern-generating programs to cut the "fishmouth" shape into the tubing.

The other approach is to have a sanding drum the diameter of the tubing to shape the end of the cross part of the T.

Answer (score 0):

I've always cut cardboard tubing (for concrete forms) with a circular saw. You could also use a table saw and roll the tube on the blade with the end against the fence for crosswise cuts.

You may have to experiment with blade tooth type to minimize fuzzing and tearout. I'd start with a thin-kerf framing blade.